# Momentum operator of a particle in an electromagnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In quantum mechanics, to all observables correspond some self-adjoint operators. In the absence of an electromagnetic field the momentum operator is clearly $\vec{P}:=\frac{\hbar}{i}\vec{\nabla}$. However in the presence of an electromagnetic field (which in QM is introduced by means of a gauge dependent potential) it is difficult to interpret $\frac{\hbar}{i}\vec{\nabla}$ as the momentum operator since it is a gauge dependent object. The natural choice seems to be $\vec{\Pi}:=\frac{\hbar}{i}\vec{\nabla}+e \vec{A}$. Is it true that measured values of the components of momentum of a particle moving in an EM field are the eigenvalues of $\vec{\Pi}$ not $\vec{P}$?